# Delete and Options requests gets a 401 unathorized response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using a .net core web api 3.1 hosted on remote IIS server, with every delete/options request I get a 401 unathorized **html** response, I allowed the CORS in my startup but no luck.

Update: this is my startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<BrmajaCommerceSearchContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SearchConnectionString")));
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", b => b.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(s =>
        {
            s.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "Ecommerce API",
                Version = "v1"
            });
            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });

        services.AddAuthentication()
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Ecommerce");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the Startup.cs? Did you mean it returns 200 when do CUR request?

Comment: @MichaelWang only GET and POST returns 200 the rest return 401, I posted the startup

Comment: If the app uses authentication/authorization features, place the call to `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` after `UseRouting` and `UseCors`, but before `UseEndpoints`. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure).

Comment: @MichaelWang it's an IIS issue as the request doesn't reach the api it's get blocked by the IIS that return 401 html response

Comment: I don't get it. You could try moveup UseCors before UseAuthorization as the link I posted and restart your service on IIS.

Comment: @MichaelWang I tried but no luck

Comment: could  u post your scheme of authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by enabling all verbs on the iis server -> .NET Authorization Rules
[image: iis server -> .NET Authorization Rules]

Answer (score 2):

The most probable reason for described behaviour is IIS WebDAV module serving those HTTP verbs. You have to disable it using IIS configuration manager or with web.config file containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

Comment: I'm using .net core there is no web.config

Comment: If you use IIS you can certainly place web.config into the root of your web application and IIS will use it. Trust me :)

Comment: I have uninstalled the cors feature from the iis server but no luck.

Comment: @KasperRoma my answer doesn't relate to CORS. You have to disable WebDAV module one way or another. If you have access to IIS configuration manager you can just remove it from Modules page, or you can uninstall WebDAV Publishing from  Common HTTP Features using Server Manager, or you simply can publish web.config with your application as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Sorry I missed it, i mean I have uninstalled WebDAV Publishing.